# Make a stake program for my own nft project

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

Friends, I want to stake my own nft project.  I wonder if there is a tool like candy machine for this?  How can I make a staking program?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on building a staking platform right now, but still WIP.

You can checkout floppylabs , gemfarm, cardinal. These are all platforms where you can basically set up staking for your project and use their program.